# Looking for an extensive set of email addresses in both good and wrong format for regular expressions testing

Tags: regex, testing, test-data

I would like to test a couple of regular expressions for email address validation, but I don't want to make up the testing set of addresses myself. I think I would not cover all the possibilities very well just by myself, and I feel like this is the "reinventing the wheel" situation, as this had to be done many times before.

Most of my search results yield resources about writing the regular expressions themselves (which I don't need), but I am unable to find any "testing data" for these regular expressions.

Do some databases or collections of such testing data exist at all, and not only for email addresses?

And if yes, are these available online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple pages with some email addresses:

- http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/tests/
- http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php

But I'd recommend reading at least the first 3 answers to this question: [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Comment: Thanks, those lists are the kind of thing I was looking for.